# Opportunity Child Query on Contact

Tags: apex, soql

The following query is working, but I am not sure why:

```
select Id, (SELECT id FROM opportunities ) from Contact
```

I was always under the impression that there was no relationship between the contact and opportunity besides the opportunity contact role. Is there an edge case that I am not accounting for? We have a lookup to contacts on the opportunity - is that why this query is working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's actually a standard field called Opportunity ContactId. This is where the data is coming from. I'm not sure why this field isn't in the documentation, but I found this field in my org, and the query also worked.

Edit: Per comments, this field appears to be deprecated and/or unused. I also could not find it in Setup, although it does appear in the Developer Console. You shouldn't try to use this field.

Comment: I was under the impression this was a backend field SF was going to use many moons ago but then decided to deprecate in a maintenance release. Seems that is not the case. I'd highly recommend some good unit testing to ensure the next (or any future) release does not screw up the SOQL.

Comment: @TSmith I couldn't find a link on that. I wonder if we could find anything on it. I was surprised to find it existed in the first place. It doesn't show up in Setup, but *does* appear in the Developer Console (Ctrl-Shift-O, Opportunity.obj).

Comment: @sfdxfox a [blog post](https://gokubi.com/archives/mystery-contact-id-field-on-opportunity) with a Force.com Product Manager comment might help. Although, it is quite old.

Comment: @TSmith Oh, that's a great find. I presume this probably just got sat on the backburner, since there's ways to accomplish this task using automation.